# how do I join and center attributes of the same name in a DataFrame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I'm working with some data in R, and I have a dataframe with data from areas and mining projects, so some areas have more than one type of project. In this case, I would like to gather data from areas that have the same name, differentiating only the types of projects that each area has, as in the example below:

- Example of how my table looks

[image]

- How would I like to organize them:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to restructure your data, or present a table in use for data visualization?

If you want to restructure your data, you can either use [`dplyr::chop()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/chop.html) or [`dplyr::nest()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html).

In your case, [`dplyr::chop()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/chop.html) is most likely what you want. The links provided show some great examples. If your frame is called `df`, this is how you might use it:

```r
nested_df <- chop(df, c(mining, project_number))
```

Comment: Actually I want to present a data frame for visualization, I believe it is more practical to do this in excel, but thanks anyway, I didn't know these functions and they will be useful for me.

Comment: That might be the case, yes. Otherwise, here is an overwhelming, but informative, overview of some packages to use to make tables. https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/